# AWS Athena Federated Query - GENERIC_USER_ERROR when running DB query for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-athena

Hi all,

I am trying to execute queries on a postgresql database I created in AWS.

I added a data source to Athena, I created the data source for postgresql and I created the lambda function.

In Lambda function I set:

- default connection string
- spill_bucket and spill prefix (I set the same for both: 'athena-spill'.  In the S3 page I cannot see any athena-spill bucket)
- the security group --> I set the security group I created to access the db
- the subnet --> I set one of the database subnet
  I deployed the lambda function but I received an error and I had to add a new environment variable created with the connection string but named as 'dbname_connection_string'.

After adding this new env variable I am able to see the database in Athena but when I try to execute any query on this database as:

```
select * from tests_summary limit 10;
```

I receive this error after running query:

```
GENERIC_USER_ERROR: Encountered an exception[com.amazonaws.SdkClientException] from your LambdaFunction[arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:449809321626:function:data-production-athena-connector-nina-lambda] executed in context[retrieving meta-data] with message[Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:443 [s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/52.219.170.25] failed: connect timed out]
This query ran against the "public" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum  or contact customer support  with Query Id: 3366bd80-143e-459c-a4da-5350b5ab4a77
```

What could be causing the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

**Root Cause:**

VPC have no internet connection issue, causing Lambda can't access S3.

**Solution:**

Add VPC Gateway Endpoint (Select **com.amazonaws.eu-central-1.s3**) in Lambda associated VPC.